# Evaluate the following definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{\cos 2x}{2\cos^2x}}dx$$

It seems that the anti-derivetive of the integrant cannot be written as elementary functions. How to evaluate this?

Comment: There are methods related to the field of [complex analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analysis), specifically [contour integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration) and the [residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).

Comment: @Lucian I think this problem can be done in real analysis methods,since this is really a calculus problem.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, but *Mathematica* has been running for over ten minutes now without being able to find a primitive for the function, so I'd be really surprised if that were the case.

Answer (score 6):

This is an instance of the family of integrals so called *Coxeter's integrals* and is closely related to *Ahmed's integrals*.

You can find my solution [here](http://sos440.tistory.com/212).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

> $$ \cos(2x)= 2\cos^2 x -1. $$

Comment: acturually I tried this, but stuck somehow